# How to activate "custom fields" section in WP3

Tags: custom-field, wp-admin, screen-options

This is probably a stupid question, but I am setting up a finnish Wordpress installation. The "custom fields" section in the "write post" section is gone; I gather it is hidden by default.

That is a great step, but my finnish is a bit rusty, it's my first WP install, and I can't for the life of me find the switch to turn it on.

Where do I do this?

> **Edit:** Martin shows a way to do this on a per-post basis, thanks for that. In my case, it would be useful to *always* show custom fields, so extra brownie points for anybody who can give me a hint on how to do that. I can't find any documentation on this.

Comment: p.s. there is no such thing as "WP3". There is WP 3.0, and WP 3.1, but "WP3" is a non-entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per default some meta boxes are hidden. These boxes are stored in an array which you can find in `wp-admin/includes/template.php#get_hidden_meta_boxes()`. There is a filter, and therefore a chance for a plugin:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/*
Plugin Name: Enable Custom Fields per Default
Version:     1.0
Required:    3.1
Author:      Thomas Scholz
Author URI:  http://toscho.de
License:     GPL
*/
! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) and exit;
add_filter( 'default_hidden_meta_boxes', 'enable_custom_fields_per_default', 20, 1 );

/**
 * Removes custom fields from the default hidden elements.
 *
 * The original ( wp-admin/includes/template.php#get_hidden_meta_boxes() ):
 * array(
 *      'slugdiv',
 *      'trackbacksdiv',
 *      'postcustom',      <-- we need this
 *      'postexcerpt',
 *      'commentstatusdiv',
 *      'commentsdiv',
 *      'authordiv',
 *      'revisionsdiv'
 * )
 *
 * It has no effect if the user has decided to hide the box.
 * This option is saved in "metaboxhidden_{$screen->id}"
 *
 * @param  array $hidden
 * @return array $hidden
 */
function enable_custom_fields_per_default( $hidden )
{
    foreach ( $hidden as $i => $metabox )
    {
        if ( 'postcustom' == $metabox )
        {
            unset ( $hidden[$i] );
        }
    }
    return $hidden;
}
```

As you can see, it is quite simple to enable more fields.

Comment: Sweet, thanks a lot! This makes the change completely globally.

Answer (score 6):

Go to edit/create a page or post in wp-admin at the top is a "Screen Options" panel link, here you can enable custom fields for that particular page or post.

[image: Screen Options tab (closed)]
[image: Screen Options tab (opened)]

The number of metaboxes displayed by default [was reduced in 3.1](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14212). If you want to change the default for all users you can hook into [the `default_hidden_meta_boxes` filter](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.2/wp-admin/includes/template.php#L1055).

Comment: Got it. Thanks! I'll leave this question open in case somebody comes up with a permanent option to show this field, which I would prefer. But this helps me for the moment.

Comment: This isn't a per post setting. Once you've changed your screen options, you'll see custom fields on your post edit screen for all posts.